# Multiple processes value of signal

Tags: vhdl

If i have 2 separate processes in 2 different components

One with:
address_regIM <= address_regIM + 1

And another with:
y <= address_regIM

If address_regIM has an initial value, what will be the value of y?

Will it be the incremented value or the initial value since all process statements are executed in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both processes are triggered by the same event, y should get the value of address_regIM before the event occurred.  If the process containing y is somehow triggered by the actions of the process that changed address_regIM, it will get the incremented value.  For each tick, it goes evaluate then assign, since if assignment triggered reevaluation on the same tick, you could get into infinite loops by (for example) putting x <= y in one process, and y <= not x in another.

Comment: So if the process with the incrementation changes a signal in the sensitivity list of the process containing y, y will be the incremented value?

Comment: That's correct, because the process with y would run in the next "tick" after the increment takes effect.  This sequence would be:  evaluate -> assign new values -> check for triggered events -> evaluate y -> update y.